# Unit of power in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0/power

Tags: 12.04, kernel

The power consumed by a processor in a multicore in idle mode in linux is provided in the following file

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0/power
```

The output is:

```
4294967295
```

In linux documentation, it is given that the unit of power consumption in milli watt. That implies the above power = 4294 Kilo watt.

Can some one help me to understand how this can be so huge?

Comment: Incidentally, 4294967295 is FFFFFFFF in hexadecimal. I bet that isn't really the power consumption.

Comment: Of note that this would only mostly happen to the old [acpi_idle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405775/acpi-idle-vs-intel-idle) driver. Intel_ide should come with a [lookup table](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/pm/intel_idle.html) that replaces reading FADT from the firmware.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, these values are taken from tables supplied by your BIOS, so it seems your motherboard vendor didn't bother filling in the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

4294967295 is the 32 bit unsigned representationof the signed value -1. In other words this would be better output as -1 or "unspecified". State 0 is when the processor is running normally (not in an idle state) and the power usage in this state is highly variable.